# Writing your own javascript and using the Yii PHP framework?

Tags: php, javascript, yii

I'm eying the Yii PHP framework for a new project, but after going through a few demos and checking out the code I'm noticing all javascript is generated through Yii functions. Is there anyway to override this? I really want to be able to write my own javascript for sections of the project, specifically for a map based search piece that requires a lot of javascript. Is this possible and is it worth using Yii for a project where I'll have to write a ton of my own javascript for a few sections of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can write a ton of Javascript yourself if you cannot or do not want to use the built-in widgets; but many times "writing your own" might turn out to be subclassing a widget so that you can extend it or just writing your own widget from scratch. In my experience being able to have Javascript be auto-generated from a higher-level specification you provide (i.e. configuring a widget) is very desirable.

From your question though it seems that there are specific cases of automatic Javascript that look troubling -- can you perhaps update with specifics?

Comment: Sure, I was looking at examples for cascading drop downs and noticed it was generating 100% of your javascript and you just passed in jquery selectors of your output divs. Which, by the way, is pretty nice, but if you have front end devs working on front end code and back end devs working on back end code, that looks like it could get a little messy.

Comment: Also meant to add that we might be taking the wrong approad to this based off of how our development team works. Though, it's really good news that you can extend widgets or write your own widgets from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

While Yii has helpers that generate some JavaScript code for you, nothing prevents you from including code of your own in your output.